# roll back org-mode version

Tags: org-mode

I have a [scimax](https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax) based configuration and my source block fontification is broken. I suspect it has to do with the release of Org-mode 9.3 which I am currently using. Thats why I am trying to roll-back the org version.

How can I install org-plus-contrib (or even just org 9.2) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to emacs.SE! Is your question about downgrading org to version 9.2? Also what's scimax? Is it usefull to know to answer the question?

Comment: I have added a link to scimax repo. I am simply trying to roll-back the org-mode version to see if that fixes my bug. I mentioned scimax so that other users with the same problem can find it. Thank you

Comment: old versions of packages are available on elpa.gnu.org/packages/org.html, I guess it's doable to manually install such an old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no builtin roll-back available from emacs builtin package manager, so you have to do it manually.

You could follow the [install instructions in the org-mode manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html):

1. Go to [Org-mode homepage](https://orgmode.org/)
2. Click on [browse the development version from code.orgmode.org](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode)
3. Click on [releases](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/releases)
4. download the release you'd like to use in you case, probably [version 9.2.6](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/archive/release_9.2.6.tar.gz)
5. unpack this downloaded archive into your home directory (i.e. `~/.emacs.d/org-mode`) and remember that location!
6. enter that location from within a command line and run `make autoloads`
7. edit your emacs init files and add the lines at the end of this post
8. open package list with `M-x list-packages` and uninstall org-mode version 9.3
9. restart emacs

Optional: run `make doc` same way like you did with `make autoloads` to generate info and pdf manuals.

---

How to revert those changes to use a recent version of org-mode again:

1. remove the aditional lines from your emacs init files
2. reinstall org-mode from package manager `M-x list-packages`
3. restart emacs
4. remove the older downloaded org-mode version (i.e. `rm ~/.emacs.d/org-mode`)

Thats it.

---

lines to add to emacs init files (with example path):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/org-mode/lisp")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/org-mode/contrib/lisp" t)
```

Comment: great answer, thank you!